# My app wont run on the emulator of android studio

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

[image]

emulator starts but there is no app on it besides it takes a lot of time to load. Is it because of windows?

Comment: Quite unclear what you are asking. Your title should also be a question.

Answer (score 0):

If u have a device that runs on an Android operation system, you can run your app on that device, and it will be much faster. Andriod Studio and it's emulators require a lot of resources. So if you don't have a decent amount of RAM available for the program, it will slow down. If you still want to use the emulator,try closing applications you are not using. Like internet browsers, games, etc..  modify vitual memory pageing file size.